# .htaccess simple rule doesn't work

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm trying to make my URL's more friendly, so

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /      E   
Rewriterule ^album/(.*)/ album.php?album_id=$1


AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

RewriteRule ^$ ?album_id=%1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.mydomain.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.mydomain.com
```

But it doesn't work.
I tried to see the error log, but there is nothing.
Someone can help me to fix it?

Comment: If there is nothing in your error logs, then I suspect this file is not seen / interpreted by your server. If this `.htaccess` is in your root directory, and you have set permissions to that directory so override is off (`AllowOverride None` is the default for home directory), then no commands will be seen (`.htaccess` is ignored). What is your configuration? Is this in the .httpd.conf file, or in .htaccess?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this rule: 
`RewriteRule ^$ ?album_id=%1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L,NC]`?

Comment: Did you turn on logging with the maximum level - something like `       RewriteLog "/var/log/apache2/rewrite.log"  RewriteLogLevel 9` in your `httpd.conf` file should show every attempt to read this file, and how it's interpreted...